# Building my first smart contract application

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm new to the dApps world but I would like to learn more by trying to build a blockchain-based application that helps to authenticate products.

for example, if we have a Gucci bag, this application would help us to know if it is fake or not.

I'm lost in understanding the workflow of the application, what I'm understanding so far is this:

create the product record: in this stage, the product is added to the blockchain and the QR code is created.

verify the product: application would scan the product and check if this product exists in the nodes of the blockchain or not.

I'm indenting to build this application with truffle framework.

can anybody advise or guide me to any sources that could help me in this project?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should start by making all Truffles Tutorial : https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials

The Solidity docs : https://solidity.readthedocs.io

This Kauri article helps too.

- https://kauri.io/remix-ide-your-first-vyper-smart-contract/15b95281c17a4954a5278865bbc0f515/a